# synchronization object

Tags: c#, locking

Please have a look at the code below.

I have two qs.

What is the advantage of using this type of object to lock?

Second q, can i manipulate the **buffer** while code is still in **//--------** this region ?

```
private list<byte> buffer;
.
.
.

lock(buffer)
{
  //--------
}
```

Comment: Advantage compared to what?

Comment: There is no question here. Where are your threads?

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem. You can read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: @Oded, Guessing he wants to know how it is compared to a syncroot instead.

Comment: please look at the updated q. and also can you address my second q as well

Comment: `lock(anything)` doesn't actually lock `anything`, it merely forces all threads to wait at the `lock` until `anything` has been freed. In other words: Another thread can still work on `anything`, so long as it doesn't have to pass the `lock`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the advantage of using this type of object to lock?

Why would there be an advantage to a specific type of lock object? As the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on, or a private static object variable to protect data common to all instances.

---

> Can I manipulate the buffer while code is still in //-------- this region ?

Yes, from the same thread the `lock()` statement was issued from. Other threads will have to wait there.

Answer (score 1):

locks are used to prevent multiple access to objects in a multi-threaded environment.
In practice, a lock is an implementation of the Monitor class in the .NET framework